# Linq data from two table with aggregate functions

Tags: c#, linq

I have two tables (Product and Review)

**Product**

> ```
> ProductId
> ProductName
> ImagePath
> CategoryID
> ```

**Review**

> ```
> ReviewId
> ProductId
> ReviewText
> ```

I want a result set which show productName, ImagePath and total reviews for the product.

I write a sql query for that like this

```
select ProductName, ImagePath,COUNT(rw.ProductId) TotalReview 
from Product pr join Review rw on pr.ProductId = rw.ProductId 
where pr.CategoryID=1
group by ProductName, ImagePath
```

Please help.

Comment: Are you writing linq query or sql query?

Comment: Just change the `join` to `inner join` and remove the group by

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad join without extra modifiers _is_ an inner join.

Comment: Rohit: I want a linq with same result as above sql query gives.                                            Hossein Narimani Rad : please read above comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the EF Linq code for your query

```
   var query = from p in db.Products
          where p.CategoryID = 1
          select new {
             Name = p.ProductName,
             ImagePath = p.ImagePath,
             TotalReviews = p.Reviews.Count()                
          };

    var results = query.ToList();
```

Comment: Where second table (Reviews) reference is?

Comment: Using EF (Entity Framework) you have that reference made. y0uri in the answer bellow is showing how to make that mapping. My answer provides you the Linq Query for your answer.

Comment: Line TotalReviews = p.Reviews.Count() gives error as follows. 'Reviewer.Product' does not contain a definition for 'Reviews' and no extension method 'Reviews' accepting a first argument of type                                          'Reviewer.Product' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: I just use ADO.NET Entity Data Model. It generates all models for me.

Comment: You need to have that property, if not in plural it is singular word.... or similar to that..... Just open the diagram that was created and look at the "Propery" names, or right mouse click on that file and choose to see the source code and there you will see ALL properties... if there are none regarding this navigation, then the problem is in the DB that does not have a REAL DB relation.

Comment: Thanks  Dryadwoods. Now below code work for me. I just make relation in DB table and then recreate edmx. If you can help please tell me how I can get rid of recreation of edmx again n again. Should I need to do similar to y0uri's code below? Please help

Answer (score 0):

You will love to do it with Entity Framework:
If you have not done so, add the Entity Framework Nuget Package to your project.

Then add the following classes:

```
[Table("Product")]
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int ProductId {get;set;}
    public string ProductName {get;set;}
    public string ImagePath {get;set;}

    [InverseProperty("Product")]
    public virtual ICollection<Review> Reviews {get;set;}
}

[Table("Review")
public class Review
{
    [Key]
    public int ReviewId {get;set;}
    public int ProductId {get;set;}
    public string ReviewText {get;set;}

    [ForeignKey("ProductId")]
    public virtual Product Product {get;set;}
}

public class YourDbContext : DbContext
{
    static YourDbContext()
    {
        //This prevents your database to be created or updated by EF
        //I prefer to keep the hand on my db
        Database.SetInitializer<YourDbContext>(null);
    }

    public YourDbContext()
        //The name value is the name of your connectionstring (in App.config or Web.config)
        //<configuration><connectionStrings><add ...
        : base("Name=YourDbContext"){}

    public DbSet<Product> Products {get;set;}
}
```

You can then access your Products with:

```
var dbContext = new YourDbContext();
var allProjects = dbContext.Projects;
var specificProject = dbContext.Projects.Where(p => p.ProductId == 5);

//Related Reviews will be availlable here
var specificReviews = specificProject.Reviews;
```

Have fun!